# Unable to access file

Tags: linux, file, permissions, sudo, su

Let's suppose we have a file test.txt with file permission 644 in server1. (File owner is cuser)

-rw-r--r-- 1 cuser cuser 6 Jul 10 09:43 test.txt

And we have 2 other users (user1 & user2) in the same server server1 with different permissions.

Both switch user to cuser.

In the above scenario is this possible that one of them might not be able to access test.txt? (In my understanding both should have the same level of access to the file after switching user)

Answer (score 0):

Once you switch user, the permission of cuser will be used and not of the original user. Also I suggest not to switch user, instead add the user1 and user2 to a group and set the group permission to the file. This was the file is more secured and the users will be  more accountable for any file changes.